# Cordova electron and SQLCipher integration

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cordova, electron, sqlcipher

I am trying to run my Cordova React app on Mac using cordova-electron [Cordova Electron](https://github.com/apache/cordova-electron) and [journeyapps/node-sqlcipher](https://github.com/journeyapps/node-sqlcipher).

I am using these versions:

```
"cordova-electron": "^3.1.0",
"@journeyapps/sqlcipher": "^5.3.1"
```

When I want to access @journeyapps/sqlcipher using require I am getting the following error:

```
window.require('@journeyapps/sqlcipher').verbose();
```

Error:
*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.require is not a function*

When I use:

```
"cordova-electron": "^1.1.1",
"@journeyapps/sqlcipher": "^4.1.0"
```

everything is working okay.

I read this article: https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/docs/newtoelectron.md but I am not sure if this example can help solve my issue.
I also read this article about removing nodeIntegration completely: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23506.

My current browserWindow settings:

```
{
    "browserWindow": {
        "width": 1280,
        "height": 768,
        "webPreferences": {
            "nodeIntegration": true,
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this issue or has working solution?

Thanks

Comment: `nodeIntegration` is insecure because it potentially allows free reign over system APIs. [Context isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) is what you should use instead, which allows you to have NodeJS code and expose a specific API without exposing an API that could be exploited dangerously.

Comment: You'll also need to create a cordova plugin that also provides the interface to the "frontend" browser, which runs in a different, non-nodeJS javascript environment. There's no documentation for this yet, but you can look at existing plugins with an `electron` implementation, such as https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device for a simple example.